EventCallBack is not working with @rendermode.InteractiveServer on a component
EventCallBack is not working with @rendermode.InteractiveServer on a component.
The OnClick.InvokeAsync() is called but does not execute. The parent callback is not called.
If @rendermode InteractiveServer is on the page and not the component the EventCallBack works.
I need to have InteractiveServer & InteractiveWebAssembly components on the same page.
I'm using .Net 8

I started with a new 'Blazor Web App' project a with Interative render mode of 'Auto (Server and WebAssembly) and Interactivity location of 'Per page/component.
Include sample pages.
Place the Home.razor in the server project and the Button.razor in both the server and client projects.
I added the WebAssembly button to the orignal Home.razor page.
No other changes were made.
Home.razor
@page "/"

<Button @rendermode=InteractiveServer OnClick=@DoOnClick Text="InteractiveServer" />

<BlazorApp.Client.Pages.Button @rendermode=InteractiveWebAssembly OnClick=@DoOnClick Text="InteractiveWebAssembly" />

<p>@HelloString</p>

@code {
  string HelloString { get; set; } = "";

  void DoOnClick()
  {
    HelloString = "Hello"; // Is not being called
  }
}

Button.razor
<button @onclick=@DoOnClick>@Text</button>

@code {
  [Parameter]
  public EventCallback OnClick { get; set; }

  [Parameter]
  public string Text { get; set; } = "";

  void DoOnClick()
  {
    OnClick.InvokeAsync(); // Is being called
  }
}


Find App.razor file and change <Routes> like below.
 <Routes @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />

Then we can fix the issue.



Adding that makes the InteractiveWebAssembly fail with:
Cannot create a component of type 'BlazorApp.Client.Components.Button' because its render mode 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode' is not supported by interactive server-side rendering.
'<BlazorApp.Client.Components.Button @rendermode=InteractiveWebAssembly OnClick=@SayHelloHandler Text="InteractiveWebAssembly" />'
My understanding of adding it to the  in App.razor is that it make all of the child components InteractiveServer.

Hi @Bill Please share how you create the project and add Button component in which  project. Please provide enough information and we can help you.

I've updated my question to reflex your question.

@Bill Will check it next Monday.

Hi @Bill After investigating the issue, seems we have to create a shared project like .net 7 template can fix the issue. Not found any good solutions in .net 8.
